# How can I read multiple matrices from one csv-file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matrix

I'm trying to load multiple matrices from a text file.

I want to read several matrices from the same file so that I can draw them in a network. I've managed to do it when to input file only contains one matrix, but don't understand how to do it when it has many. 
The input file looks something like this, only it is a big bigger:

```
x [*,*,0]
:    0   1   2   3   4   :=
0    .   0   0   1   1   
1    1   .   0   0   0   
2    1   0   .   0   0   
3    0   0   0   .   0   
4    0   0   0   0   .
```

And my code is like this:

```
infile = "testfile.sol"
edges = []
import pandas as pd
colNames = [i for i in range(11)]
df = pd.read_csv('testfile.sol', sep=' ', skipinitialspace=True, index_col=0,names=colNames, skiprows=[0, 1])

for i in range(len(df)):
    for j in range(len(df)):
        if df[i][j] == "1":
            index_i = i
            index_j = j
            edge = (i,j)
            edges.append(edge)
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(edges)
```

This sort of works, but my input file has several of these written further down the file:

```
x [*,*,0]
:    0   1   2   3   4   :=
0    .   0   0   1   1   
1    1   .   0   0   0   
2    1   0   .   0   0   
3    0   0   0   .   0   
4    0   0   0   0   .   

x [*,*,1]
:    0   1   2   3   4   :=
0    .   0   0   1   0   
1    1   .   0   0   0   
2    1   0   .   0   1   
3    0   0   0   .   0   
4    0   0   0   0   .
```

How can I read all of these, and make the lists edges0, edges1, and so on?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try it but you may use numpy.genfromtxt() with correct delimiters. You need to use two times. First get matrices and use second time by iterating on matrices array.